# Environment properties not working after deployment in EC2 dotnet core app

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, azure, .net-core, amazon-ec2

Environment class in DOTNET exposes certain properties. In that there is a prop to get env variable value

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")

This gives proper value in local machine as "Development" but when I deployed this in IIS server inside a EC2 instance, somehow this is coming as Empty.

Is there any configuration I have to do inside deployment environment ?

Comment: You need to add a configuration setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with value according to the environment

Comment: @akb thanks for your quick reply :)  Did you mean that I have to add this key-value in Environment variables of System inside the Virtual machine or any other configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

When we were using the ISS we added the web.config file specifically to supply the environment variable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="QA" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```